# Debug python tensorflow issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a audio set to train a neural network using **tensorflow** library but there is a weird issue that I can't figure out. So I am following this blog [Urban Sound Classification](http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/), the only difference is that I have my own dataset.

So everything is working fine if I have small data like about 30 audio files or so but when I use the complete data my training code simply runs couple of iterations outputs cost and then that is about it, no error, exception or warning is thrown the tensorflow session simply doesn't give any further results. Let's see the code to better explanation:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
for epoch in range(training_epochs):            
    _,cost = sess.run([optimizer,cost_function],feed_dict={X:tr_features,Y:tr_labels})
    cost_history = np.append(cost_history,cost)

y_pred = sess.run(tf.argmax(y_,1),feed_dict={X: ts_features})
y_true = sess.run(tf.argmax(ts_labels,1))
print("Test accuracy: ",round(session.run(accuracy, 
    feed_dict={X: ts_features,Y: ts_labels}),3))
```

So when I run the above code for training on complete data (about 9000 files) it generates cost history for about 2 epochs and then stop generation history but the code keeps on executing like normal jus the session.run() stop outputting results. My guess is that due to some exception the session stops but how do I debug this stupid error? I have nothing to go on. Can anyone advise on this?

Note: I am not sure if this is the right forum but point me in right direction I will move the question if need be.

**UPDATE 01:**

So I have figured some correlation between the amount of data/learning rate and the error. Here is my understanding of what is happening. So when I was coding I used subset of my original data about 10-15 files for training and the learning rate was 0.01 and it worked well (as in it completed all it's epochs).

When I used 500 files for training it repeated the same behavior as described in original question (it would output 2 iterations and then kaboom not more outputs and no exception or error). I noticed in those iterations that cost was increasing so I tried to lower the learning rate, and viola it worked like a charm with a new learning rate of 0.001. (again all epochs ran and successfully outputted the results)

Finally when I run the training for all of my data that is about 9000 files but I observed the same behavior as previously discussed. So my question now is how much should I lower the learning rate? What is the correlation of the learning rate to the amount of data?

Comment: Although I *think* I can guess the intention of your code it's hard to be sure since indentation is very important in Python. Please fix the indentation in your code example to be exactly the same as what you're running.

Comment: hi thanks for getting back on this. the indentation is not the issue, I assure you it is well indented in the code. I have made some progress with debugging perhaps you can comment some opinion after reading the update 01.